# AngularJS creating a controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Can anyone figure out why this might not be displaying? The View1.html and View2.html docs are in place in the partials folder. Sometimes I just get a completely blank screen, sometimes I get a Name: and text box, sometimes I get View1 but never do I get the customer names. Thanks..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="demoApp">
<head>
<base href="/"> <!-- needed for Angular HTML 5 mode -->
    <title>Angular Todo</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost:8080/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:8080/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:8080/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:8080/bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:8080/bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
    </script>

    <style>
    .container{
        padding: 20px;
        background-color: green;
    }

    </style>

</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <div data-ng-view></div>

    </div>

        <script>

        var demoApp = angular.module('demoApp', []);

            demoApp.config(function ($routeProvider){
                $routeProvider
                .when('/',
                {
                        controller: 'SimpleController',
                        templateUrl: 'Partials/View1.html'
                })
                .when('/view2',
                {
                        controller: 'SimpleController'
                        templateUrl: 'Partials/View2.html'
                })
                .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/'});

            });


                demoApp.controller('SimpleController', function ($scope) {
                $scope.customers = [{ 
                        name: 'John Doe', city: 'New York' 
                    }, 
                    { 
                        name: 'John Smith', city: 'Phoenix' 
                    }, 
                    { 
                        name: 'Jane Doe', city: 'San Francisco' 
                    }
                    ];

                    $scope.addCustomer= function (){
                        $scope.customers.push(
                            { name: $scope.newCustomer.name. city: $scope.newCustomer.city
                            });
                    };
                });

        </script>



<script src='js/controller.js'></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not displaying anything. Try this

```
    <li data-ng-repeat="cust in customers | filter:name | orderBy: 'name'">
    {{cust.name}}:{{cust.city}}
    </li>
```

```js
var demoApp = angular.module('demoApp', []);

demoApp.controller('SimpleController', function($scope) {
  $scope.customers = [{
      name: 'John Doe',
      city: 'new york'
    },
    {
      name: 'john smith',
      city: 'phoenix'
    },
    {
      name: 'jane doe',
      city: 'san francisco'
    }
  ];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="demoApp" class="container" data-ng-controller="SimpleController">

  Name:
  <br />
  <input type="text" data-ng-model="name" />
  <br />
  <ul>
    <li data-ng-repeat="cust in customers | filter:name | orderBy: 'name'">
    {{cust.name}}:{{cust.city}}
    </li>
  </ul>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You forget to bind the properties

```
<li data-ng-repeat="cust in customers | filter:name | orderBy: 'name'">

         <span ng-bind="cust.name"></span>

</li>
```